# Softwares to determine semi-simple types of Lie algebras generated over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ by a set of matrices

Tags: lie-algebras, computer-algebra, mathematical-software, gap

I wish to determine the type of a Lie algebra generated over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ by a set of square matrices with irrational elements. For example,

\begin{align}
  n^+ = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 
  \end{pmatrix}, \quad
  n^- =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 1 \\
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & 0 & 0 
  \end{pmatrix}, \quad
  n^3 =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
    0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & 0 
  \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
I've been using `GAP` and it is quite good at determining the type of Lie algebras over $\mathbb{Q}$, which seems to work fine when all the matrix elements are rational numbers. However, when the matrices contain irrational numbers, if I still work with Lie algebras over $\mathbb{Q}$, I would get a larger Lie algebra, and in the above example, I got 8 copies of $A_1$. On the other hand, If I work with Lie algebras over cyclotomic numbers, the function `SemiSimpleType` would break down. Therefore I wish to know:

Is there a way of doing this with `GAP`? If not, are there any other softwares which can do this?

Comment: Don't have an answer but for this particular example I get a 6-dimensional semisimple algebra over the 24th cyclotomic field. Over $\mathbb C$ it is clearly two copies of $A_1$. That's all I can say, unfortunately.

Comment: If this helps, `GAP` gives the following basis for this algebra: $e_{11}-e_{33}$, $e_{12}+e_{23}$, $e_{21}+e_{32}$, $e_{14}+e_{43}/\sqrt3$, $e_{24}-e_{42}/\sqrt3$, $e_{34}+e_{41}/\sqrt3$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე May I know how did you get this in ```GAP```? Thanks!

Comment: `a:=1/Sqrt(2);` `b:=1/Sqrt(3)`; `np:=[[0,-a,0,1],[0,0,-a,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,b,0]];` `nm:=[[0,0,0,0],[a,0,0,0],[0,a,0,1],[b,0,0,0]];` `n3:=[[a,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,-a,0],[0,-b,0,0]];` `ma:=MatrixLieAlgebra(CF(24),4);` `a:=Subalgebra(ma,[LieObject(np),LieObject(nm),LieObject(n3)]);` whereafter `LeviMalcevDecomposition(a);` returns `[ <Lie algebra of dimension 6 over CF(24)>, <Lie algebra of dimension 0 over CF(24)> ]` and `for b in CanonicalBasis(a) do Display(b); od;` gives these matrices

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Thanks! The function ```CanonicalBasis()``` is helpful for me. It seems for this particular example it is easy to get the semisimple type over $\mathbb{R}$ by combining the results from over $\mathbb{Q}$ and over $CF(24)$. I guess ```GAP``` would not be able to deal with matrices with transcendental elements, although I am not sure whether I will encounter such case.

Comment: Occasionally I worked with Lie algebras over purely transcendental extensions like `FunctionField(Rationals,"x","y","z")` say. Not sure if more general fields would work, never encountered these.